# What does --> mean in Perl 6?

Tags: syntax, raku

On Rossetta code, [the Perl 6 code for Levenshtein distance](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Perl_6), the subroutine signature contains `Str $t --> Int`.

Is the `-->` an operator acting on `$t` or something else altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It specifies a [return constraint](http://doc.raku.org/routine/returns).

For example, this code requires that the return value be an integer:

```
sub add (Int $inputA, Int $inputB --> Int)
{
    my $result = $inputA+$inputB;

    say $result;         # Oops, this is the last statement, so its return value is used for the subroutine
}

my $sum = add(5,6);
```

And since it implicitly returns a Boolean as a result of the last statement being the `say` function, it throws an error:

```
11
Type check failed for return value; expected 'Int' but got 'Bool'
  in any return_error at src/vm/moar/Perl6/Ops.nqp:649
  in sub add at test.p6:5
  in block <unit> at test.p6:8
```

When you get this error, you look at your code and realize that you should have included an explicit return statement and probably printed the result outside of the subroutine:

```
sub add (Int $inputA, Int $inputB --> Int)
{
    my $result = $inputA+$inputB;

    return $result;
}

my $sum = add(5,6);
say $sum;
```

Which prints the expected answer, without any errors:

```
11
```

A more clear way to define the return type is using `returns` (Thanks [Brad Gilbert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374950/what-does-mean-in-perl-6/29374951#comment46961773_29374951)):

```
sub add (Int $inputA, Int $inputB) returns Int
{
    my $result = $inputA+$inputB;

    return $result;
}

my $sum = add(5,6);
say $sum;
```

Comment: I would have also said that there is an alternative way of writing it `sub add (Int $, Int $) returns Int {...}`